# how to define: Cartegory and subcategory in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a database table like this:

[image]

I want to make a category and subcategory like [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/categories-and-subcategories?page=1).

I have followed the steps in the link, but I face problem same as manojsharma20 on that page.

Subcategory also shows as category.

How do I avoid subcategories displaying as a category.

[image]

Comment: [link]https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/categories-and-subcategories?page=1

Comment: @james thanks for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your Model name is **Category**

1. Create a function on Category model

   public function childs()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
   }
2. using above method on your controller
   $categories = Category::with('childs')->where('parent_id',0)->get();

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working example,

**Suppose your Model name is `Category`**

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------
 * Relationship with same table, means recursive key
 * --------------------------------------------------------
 */
//using this relation, you will get parent children
public function cat_childs(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}

//using this relation, it will tell you, who is the parent of children
public function cat_parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

so using this method you will get the `parent` and its `children`

```
$list = \App\Category::with('cat_childs')->all();

//this will show you parent and its children
echo "<pre>";
   print_r($list);
echo "</pre>";
```